# How to get sibling element (div) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this HTML:

```
<div class="tip-box">
    <div class="tip-title" onclick="toggleTip()">
        <h2>Tip 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tip-content hidden">
        <p>Tip 1 content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this Javascript:

```
function toggleTip() {
    $(this).siblings(".tip-content").toggleClass("hidden");
}
```

Hopefully it's obvious what this is supposed to do, but it doesn't work. Using `.siblings()` just doesn't seem to work in this way.

What's the correct solution for this? To get the next sibling of a certain type or with a certain class and then hide/show it?

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f9tcurhk/)?

Comment: The problem is  `this` isn't what you expect.

Comment: @JoshCrozier has the right idea here. You just forgot to pass the context of the click to the function.

Comment: @JoshCrozier ha yeah I was talking to OP, saying you did it correctly :)

Comment: You would like to get only one sibling or siblings with class name `.tip-content`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Jquery function.

```
<div class="tip-box">
    <div class="tip-title">
        <h2>Tip 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tip-content hidden">
        <p>Tip 1 content</p>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tip-title').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".tip-content").toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

you can also use this

```
<div class="tip-box">
    <div class="tip-title" onclick="toggloTip(this)">
        <h2>Tip 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tip-content hidden">
        <p>Tip 1 content</p>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
function toggloTip(elm) {
    $(elm).siblings(".tip-content").toggleClass("hidden");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pure javaScript with `nextElementSibling` property of node something like below,
I suppose you want do this operation with siblings.

```js
function getChildrens(n, selector) {
  var nodes = [];
  while (n.nextElementSibling != null) {
    if (n.nextElementSibling.hasOwnProperty('classList')) {
      if (n.nextElementSibling.classList.contains(selector)) {
        //return n.nextElementSibling;
        nodes.push(n.nextElementSibling);
      }
    }
    n = n.nextElementSibling;
  }
  return nodes;
};

function getSiblings(n, selector) {
  return getChildrens(n, selector);
}

function toggleTip(elem) {
  var siblings = getSiblings(elem, "tip-content");
  if (siblings.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
      siblings[i].classList.toggle("hidden");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tip-box">
  <div class="tip-title" onclick="toggleTip(this)">
    <h2>Tip 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="tip-content hidden">
    <p>Tip 1 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You *could use pure Javascript* but why would you introduce that much new code when they are already using *one line of jQuery* (just incorrectly at the moment)? This is not practical let alone useful. Sorry.

Comment: You might be right but I was just giving another alternative solution which might be useful for other people.

Comment: Not in the scope of the question asked. Anyone finding this will see a "`onclick=""` calling jQuery without a correct `this`" problem and not be that concerned about re-implementing one line of jQuery with over 20 lines of raw JS. Sorry :(

Comment: I appreciate the pure js answer, and the question was "How to get sibling element (div) in Javascript?" so I believe it's well within the scope.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another non JQuery answer.

To get the next element sibling use:

```
var nextElement = element.nextElementSibling;
```

To get the previous element sibling use:

```
var previousElement = element.previousElementSibling;
```

To get the element index use:

```
var index = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.parentElement.children).indexOf(element);
```

If you are at the first element the previousElementSibling value will be null.

If you are at the last element the nextElementSibling value will be null.

Answer (score 1):

How about this JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('.tip-box').on('click', '.tip-title', function(){
        $(this).next('.tip-content').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Remove the idea of working with `onclick` attributes when you use jQuery.

Comment: The delegated event handler appears overkill, but yours is more sensible than the *serial-upvoted* answer by Kamruzzaman. +1

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers, not even that *serial-upvoted* one ;), actually explains the problem and *why* their solutions work.

The problem is that an inline `onclick` handler does not pass on its current context. Inside the `onclick=""` JavaScript code `this` is the element clicked. Once you call a global function (like your `toggleTip`), that context is lost. The `this` the function receives is `window` and not the element.

The usual quick fix, for raw JavaScript code, is to pass `this` as a parameter to the global function.

e.g.

```
onclick="toggleTip(this)"
```

and receive a parameter in the function like this:

```
function toggleTip(element) {
    $(element).siblings(".tip-content").toggleClass("hidden");
}
```

*However*, as you are using jQuery, inline event handlers are actually a bad idea. They separate the event registration from the event handler code for no reason and do not allow for multiple event handlers, of the same type, on the same element. They also bypass the rather cool event bubbling system jQuery uses.

The preferred alternative, with jQuery, is to use jQuery to select the element and jQuery to connect the event *in one step*:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.tip-title').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".tip-content").toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

As you only want the element that follows, and potentially will add more pairs, the better option would be using `nextAll` and `first()`, with the same jQuery filter, instead of `siblings`:

e.g.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.tip-title').click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll(".tip-content").first().toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

Or, of you can guarantee it is *the next element*, use `next` as @Tim Vermaelen did (with or without the selector makes no difference, so might as well leave it out):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.tip-title').click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

Note: In this example `jQuery(function($){` is a *DOM ready event handler* which is the rather handy shortcut version of `$(document).ready(function(){YOUR CODE});`, which also passes a locally scoped `$` value. For those that mistake this code for an incorrect [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/az4r27uz/

Comment: I have to scratch your back for the elevated explanation on "why" not using inline onclick handlers. One question though, there are many shortcuts for jQuery's DOM ready, but yours seems a bit off ... the `$` is not passed if I'm correct. Correct way should be an IIFE => `(function($){}(window.jQuery));`

Comment: @Tim Vermaelen: Nope, it is *not* an IIFE. It is a shortcut DOM ready function that jQuery provides which passes a reference to itself as the first parameter. :)

Comment: I know them, that's why it has a certain smell ... if you get my drift ... let me test that real quick.

Comment: @Tim Vermaelen: It's basically the `$(function(){});` DOM ready shortcut with a parameter. Trust me it is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/az4r27uz/ :)

Comment: Yes indeed, [seems legit](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/oppead7m/). Strange as I remember (back at version 1.7 or 8) that didn't work. Or I must have completely missed that test back then. Learned something new ^^

Comment: @Tim Vermaelen: Also works in 1.6.4 http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/az4r27uz/1/, 1.7.2 http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/az4r27uz/2/ 1.8.3 http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/az4r27uz/3/ :)

Comment: @Tim Vermaelen: Time to consider some comment housekeeping here? :)